# How to access multiple action properties in Strtus2 OGNL expression?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, expression, ognl

In my jsp I have this code:

```
<s:property value="%{(getPage()-1)*getSearchMaxEntries()+1}"/>
```

This should access the properties of the action and show the result of the calculation. Unfortunately, this always equals to `1` regardless of the real values returned by the action.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access properties you should use property names, and they should be numbers

```
<s:property value="%{(page-1)*searchMaxEntries+1}"/>
```

Comment: I changed my code and checked the get methods, both return an int. Unfortunately the result is still the same. The property is evaluted to `1`.

Comment: After all I found `"page = 1"` which sould be `"page == 1"`. Thanks for the support and the simplified expression.